# nginx+passenger and Gemfile in non-common location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rvm, passenger, gemfile

We have an application which uses non-standard rails Gemfile location. It worked with Nginx+unicorn just fine but I'm having a hard time to get it work with Nginx+Passenger. After setting `root` parameter to the Rails public folder I notice it didn't load other ruby dependencies in parents folder. I tried playing with root, passenger_app_root, passenger_document_root but no lock. Any thoughts? Here are the details.

**File Structure:**

```
symphony     <--------- Root (has the Gemfile)
├── bin/
├── common/
├── config
├── lib/    <--------- Ruby dependencies        
├── log/
├── reports/
├── schedulers/
├── timeout_daemon/
├── spec/
├── tools/
├── Gemfile        <--- The Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
└── manager        <--- Regular Rails app folder
    ├── cache/
    ├── config/
    ├── db/
    ├── lib/
    ├── log/
    ├── public/   <--- Public folder
    ├── features/
    ├── spec/
    ├── test/
    ├── vendor/
    ├── tmp/
    ├── script
    ├── config.ru
    ├── README
    ├── Rakefile
    └── app/      <--- Rails stuff
        ├── assets
        ├── controllers
        ├── decorators
        ├── helpers
        ├── mailers
        ├── models
        ├── sweepers
        ├── validators
        ├── views
        └── widgets
```

**Nginx.conf**

```
include nginx.core.conf;

http {

  include nginx.http.conf;

  passenger_ruby /home/blueserver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327-turbo@symphony/wrappers/ruby;
  passenger_root /home/blueserver/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327-turbo@symphony/gems/passenger-5.0.8;

  server {
    listen 3000 ssl deferred;

    # redirects HTTP to HTTPS
    error_page 497  https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

    # SSL Configuration
    ssl_certificate /certs/ssl_cert_and_chain;
    ssl_certificate_key /keys/ssl_key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1; # disabled the SSLv23 (POODLE)

    # passenger settings
    rails_env production;

    # shared locations nginx config
    root /home/blueserver/symphony/manager/public;

    passenger_enabled on;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

    # provide paths for the static content
    location ~* ^/assets {
      expires max;
      access_log off;
      gzip_static on;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Message from application: undefined method `acts_as_list' for #<Class:0x994c538> (NoMethodError)
```

*(Full error message here: http://pastebin.com/sgxFn8pu)*

The acts_as_list is a Gem defined in the Gemfile.

I have tried different configurations with root, passenger_app_root, passenger_document_root... like

**if:**

```
root /home/blueserver/symphony/manager/public;
passenger_app_root /home/blueserver/symphony;
```

**then get error:**

```
2015/05/28 00:27:59 [error] 29595#0: *78 directory index of "/home/blueserver/symphony/manager/public/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.101.61, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.101.45:3000"
```

I don't get the gems not found error anymore but it doesn't route with Rails. Any thoughts please?

**Versions**:

- Ubuntu-12.04
- Phusion Passenger version 5.0.8
- nginx/1.6.3
- rvm 1.25.28
- ruby 1.9.3p327
- Rails 3.2.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify [BUNDLE_GEMFILE](http://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html) variable use [passenger_env_var](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerEnvVar) directive of Passenger. Seems like in this case Bundler will known where your Gemfile is places.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `passenger_env_var BUNDLE_GEMFILE /home/blueserver/symphony/Gemfile;` did the job :)